Auto Stoplight Colored Chart
Does anyone have code that will automatically color a traffic light-type icon for a red-yellow-green status? The only way I know how to do this is with multiple steps that have to be replicated each time. I would like, for example, when the letters "R", "Y" or "G" are entered into one report field, the stoplight icon auto changes to that color at the top. Not expecting script-writing, was hoping someone had a shortcut.
What I've been able to do is to create conditional formatting when one field is completed that triggers the other field in corresponding color. It does work but thought there may be a simpler way to do this in a more automated fashion or using VBA script.

Welcome to Superuser. This site is not a script writing service nor are we a software recommendation service. What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Please consider editing your post to make that more clear, AND to add what you've already tried and how you want it improved.

Thank you M2M! Comment was moved into description. Thanks for your advice - I will remember for future use as well

The default "3 Traffic Lights" Icon Set conditional formatting works on a Low-Mid-High numeric scale for R-Y-G coloring. If you just fill that cell with one of three values rather than "R", "Y", "G", it can give you a colored icon corresponding to it. Make sure that the conditional formatting range is limited to the range of interest, or other values will rescale the range and change your thresholds.


Based on the OP's post I would add that once the initial icon set is created, one can go back and Manage Rules to customize the icon set including chaning the values related to each icon and whether to have the value displayed along with the icon (as above) or display the icon only (perhaps useful in OP's case).
